# How can I create two columns with pictures?

Tags: diagrams, two-column

I need some help. I need to put some pictures in a document with two columns and right now I'm using:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{1}
\caption{Réactions catalytiques réversibles }
\label{fig:1 Réactions catalytiques réversibles }
\end{figure}
```

But the problem is that all the pictures I put, they appear at the top of the page. It doesn't matter were I put it in the text, it always appears at the top.

Can someone can help me?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,final]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\author{Darlin Roy  \and Otaola Franco}
\title{Récupération d'énergie thermique « basses calories » (Stockage et transport d'énergie)}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{twocolumn}
        \sloppy
```

Comment: Please complete your MWE with ``\documentclass{...}`` and other essential packages which show your problem. Usually helps if you to ``\begin{figure}`` add option ``[h].

Comment: You don't NEED to use figure.  minipage and \captionof{figure} (from the caption package) will stay where you put it.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{twocolumn}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[domain=0:1] plot(\x,\x*\x);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
 \lipsum[4-5]
 \begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[domain=0:1] plot(\x,\x*\x);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
\lipsum[6-10]
\end{twocolumn}


\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, but im really new with this, but i dont understand how i can put the picture. because i use the assistant and put insert graphic, but with you wrote, i dont know hoy to choose the picture,